# Oracle ApEx 4.1.1 secure cookies

Tags: cookies, https, oracle-apex

I have been asked to look into ensuring that the cookie's that Oracle ApEx 4.1.1 is using/setting are secure.

I believe an example of this would be:

```
Set-Cookie: expires=Thu......; path=/;
```

Apparrently it should read as:

```
Set-Cookie: expires=Thu......; path=/;secure
```

Where do I need to set this in my SSO (Sentry) or is this performed on the App Server?

Answer (score 0):

APEX mostly uses server-side sessions instead of cookies.  But at any rate, looks like you had an answer posted here:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2418362

Followup for anyone searching:

> in the Session Cookie Attributes section for the authentication scheme
>   that your application is using you can select Yes for the secure
>   attribute. This is what the help says about this option: Select Yes to
>   allow the session management cookie to be sent from the browser only
>   when the protocol is HTTPS. Select No to allow the session management
>   cookie to be sent from the browser when the protocol is HTTP or HTTPS.
>
> regards, Erik-jan